# How to load Java based SecurityConfig in XML based Spring config file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I already have a XML based Spring application. I have been asked to integrate Spring Security into it. I want to use Java based config. I have already initialized it as per the instructions here: [Java Config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RC2/reference/html/jc.html#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc) but how and where do I load the `SecurityConfig` class.

My `web.xml` is:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/site.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

My `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` is:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

My `SecurityConfig` is:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `@Configuration` annotation to `SecurityConfig`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

Add component scan tag in your spring configuration XML file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="<yourPackageName>" />
```